# Grails transaction annotation

Tags: grails, transactions

How to rollback on a controller/action annotated with @Transaction in grails?

I'm saving two objects and want to rollback if any have errors.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options. Leave the annotation as-is and throw a `RuntimeException`. The default behavior of `@Transactional` is to roll back the current transaction when a `RuntimeException` is encountered. This is not a great choice for obvious reasons.

On the other hand, you could throw a checked exception from the action in question if errors are encountered. This would require a slight modification to the annotation, however:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
```

The above approach is a bit heavy-handed though, so you probably want to use the specific Exception class you intend on throwing. For example:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = IOException.class)
```